# Can't initialize tronbox using tronbox cli on Ubuntu

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, tron

I am trying to work on a smart contract in TRON and started with tronbox init following https://developers.tron.network/docs/tron-box-user-guide#initialize-a-tron-box-project

After installing tronbox cli using npm on my Ubuntu I tried to initialize the project but it is throwing the error.
I attached a screenshot.

[image]

Tried to find the solutions but didn't find the right one.
Please kindly let me know the reason why this is happening if anybody faced this one before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use nvm for Node, please install Node 8:

```
nvm install v8.16.0
nvm use v8.16.0
```

Comment: do you know why it doesn't work on current latest version of node.js?

Comment: It depends on tronbox contribute team. Please check here: https://github.com/tronprotocol/tronbox